# Xcode - How to pause video capture using OpenGL

Tags: ios, xcode, video, opengl-es

I originally wrote some code using an example CapturePause code (Here is the base example code link on Github - https://github.com/cokecoffe/ios-demo/tree/master/capturepause/CapturePause) to pause video capture, obviously the pausing the capture isn't tricky but the code below looked for the pause flag and then adjusted the time stamp on the video to make sure there was not a gap, this worked very successfully and here is the method that looked at that aspect:

```
- (void) captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
BOOL bVideo = YES;
@synchronized(self)
{
    if (!self.isCapturing  || self.isPaused)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (connection != _videoConnection)
    {
        bVideo = NO;
    }
    if ((_encoder == nil) && !bVideo)
    {
        CMFormatDescriptionRef fmt = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(sampleBuffer);
        [self setAudioFormat:fmt];
        NSString* filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"capture%d.mp4", _currentFile];
        NSString* path = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];

        //additional quality encoding strings
        if (globalheightvalue == 0){
        }
        else {
            _cy = globalheightvalue;
            _cx = globalwidthvalue;
        }


        _encoder = [VideoEncoder encoderForPath:path Height:_cy width:_cx channels:_channels samples:_samplerate];
    }
    if (_discont)
    {
        if (bVideo)
        {
            return;
        }
        _discont = NO;
        // calc adjustment
        CMTime pts = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);
        CMTime last = bVideo ? _lastVideo : _lastAudio;
        if (last.flags & kCMTimeFlags_Valid)
        {
            if (_timeOffset.flags & kCMTimeFlags_Valid)
            {
                pts = CMTimeSubtract(pts, _timeOffset);
            }
            CMTime offset = CMTimeSubtract(pts, last);
            NSLog(@"Setting offset from %s", bVideo?"video": "audio");
            NSLog(@"Adding %f to %f (pts %f)", ((double)offset.value)/offset.timescale, ((double)_timeOffset.value)/_timeOffset.timescale, ((double)pts.value/pts.timescale));

            // this stops us having to set a scale for _timeOffset before we see the first video time
            if (_timeOffset.value == 0)
            {
                _timeOffset = offset;
            }
            else
            {
                _timeOffset = CMTimeAdd(_timeOffset, offset);
            }
        }
        _lastVideo.flags = 0;
        _lastAudio.flags = 0;
    }

    // retain so that we can release either this or modified one
    CFRetain(sampleBuffer);

    if (_timeOffset.value > 0)
    {
        CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
        sampleBuffer = [self adjustTime:sampleBuffer by:_timeOffset];
    }

    // record most recent time so we know the length of the pause
    CMTime pts = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);
    CMTime dur = CMSampleBufferGetDuration(sampleBuffer);
    if (dur.value > 0)
    {
        pts = CMTimeAdd(pts, dur);
    }
    if (bVideo)
    {
        _lastVideo = pts;
    }
    else
    {
        _lastAudio = pts;
    }
}

// pass frame to encoder
[_encoder encodeFrame:sampleBuffer isVideo:bVideo];
CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
}


- (CMSampleBufferRef) adjustTime:(CMSampleBufferRef) sample by:(CMTime) offset
{
CMItemCount count;
CMSampleBufferGetSampleTimingInfoArray(sample, 0, nil, &count);
CMSampleTimingInfo* pInfo = malloc(sizeof(CMSampleTimingInfo) * count);
CMSampleBufferGetSampleTimingInfoArray(sample, count, pInfo, &count);
for (CMItemCount i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    pInfo[i].decodeTimeStamp = CMTimeSubtract(pInfo[i].decodeTimeStamp, offset);
    pInfo[i].presentationTimeStamp = CMTimeSubtract(pInfo[i].presentationTimeStamp, offset);
}
CMSampleBufferRef sout;
CMSampleBufferCreateCopyWithNewTiming(nil, sample, count, pInfo, &sout);
free(pInfo);
return sout;
}
```

Now I have switched to using code based on OpenGL for various reasons and trying to get the same functionality (Base code from here - https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage). I think I need to put something similar in this area but I am not entirely sure as the complexity of the OpenGL code is way above my head! Code area here from the file GPUImageVideoCamera.m:

```
- (void)processVideoSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer;
{
if (capturePaused)
{ return;
}
CFAbsoluteTime startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
CVImageBufferRef cameraFrame = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
int bufferWidth = (int) CVPixelBufferGetWidth(cameraFrame);
int bufferHeight = (int) CVPixelBufferGetHeight(cameraFrame);
CFTypeRef colorAttachments = CVBufferGetAttachment(cameraFrame, kCVImageBufferYCbCrMatrixKey, NULL);
if (colorAttachments != NULL)
{
    if(CFStringCompare(colorAttachments, kCVImageBufferYCbCrMatrix_ITU_R_601_4, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo)
    {
        if (isFullYUVRange)
        {
            _preferredConversion = kColorConversion601FullRange;
        }
        else
        {
            _preferredConversion = kColorConversion601;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        _preferredConversion = kColorConversion709;
    }
}
else
{
    if (isFullYUVRange)
    {
        _preferredConversion = kColorConversion601FullRange;
    }
    else
    {
        _preferredConversion = kColorConversion601;
    }
}

CMTime currentTime = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);

[GPUImageContext useImageProcessingContext];

if ([GPUImageContext supportsFastTextureUpload] && captureAsYUV)
{
    CVOpenGLESTextureRef luminanceTextureRef = NULL;
    CVOpenGLESTextureRef chrominanceTextureRef = NULL;

//        if (captureAsYUV && [GPUImageContext deviceSupportsRedTextures])
    if (CVPixelBufferGetPlaneCount(cameraFrame) > 0) // Check for YUV planar inputs to do RGB conversion
    {
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(cameraFrame, 0);

        if ( (imageBufferWidth != bufferWidth) && (imageBufferHeight != bufferHeight) )
        {
            imageBufferWidth = bufferWidth;
            imageBufferHeight = bufferHeight;
        }

        CVReturn err;
        // Y-plane
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE4);
        if ([GPUImageContext deviceSupportsRedTextures])
        {
            err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, [[GPUImageContext sharedImageProcessingContext] coreVideoTextureCache], cameraFrame, NULL, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_LUMINANCE, bufferWidth, bufferHeight, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, &luminanceTextureRef);
        }
        else
        {
            err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, [[GPUImageContext sharedImageProcessingContext] coreVideoTextureCache], cameraFrame, NULL, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_LUMINANCE, bufferWidth, bufferHeight, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, &luminanceTextureRef);
        }
        if (err)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error at CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage %d", err);
        }

        luminanceTexture = CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(luminanceTextureRef);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, luminanceTexture);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        // UV-plane
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE5);
        if ([GPUImageContext deviceSupportsRedTextures])
        {
            err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, [[GPUImageContext sharedImageProcessingContext] coreVideoTextureCache], cameraFrame, NULL, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, bufferWidth/2, bufferHeight/2, GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 1, &chrominanceTextureRef);
        }
        else
        {
            err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, [[GPUImageContext sharedImageProcessingContext] coreVideoTextureCache], cameraFrame, NULL, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, bufferWidth/2, bufferHeight/2, GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 1, &chrominanceTextureRef);
        }
        if (err)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error at CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage %d", err);
        }

        chrominanceTexture = CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(chrominanceTextureRef);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, chrominanceTexture);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

//            if (!allTargetsWantMonochromeData)
//            {
            [self convertYUVToRGBOutput];
//            }

        int rotatedImageBufferWidth = bufferWidth, rotatedImageBufferHeight = bufferHeight;

        if (GPUImageRotationSwapsWidthAndHeight(internalRotation))
        {
            rotatedImageBufferWidth = bufferHeight;
            rotatedImageBufferHeight = bufferWidth;
        }

        [self updateTargetsForVideoCameraUsingCacheTextureAtWidth:rotatedImageBufferWidth height:rotatedImageBufferHeight time:currentTime];

        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(cameraFrame, 0);
        CFRelease(luminanceTextureRef);
        CFRelease(chrominanceTextureRef);
    }
    else
    {
    }


    if (_runBenchmark)
    {
        numberOfFramesCaptured++;
        if (numberOfFramesCaptured > INITIALFRAMESTOIGNOREFORBENCHMARK)
        {
            CFAbsoluteTime currentFrameTime = (CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime);
            totalFrameTimeDuringCapture += currentFrameTime;
            NSLog(@"Average frame time : %f ms", [self averageFrameDurationDuringCapture]);
            NSLog(@"Current frame time : %f ms", 1000.0 * currentFrameTime);
        }
    }
}
else
{
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(cameraFrame, 0);

    int bytesPerRow = (int) CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(cameraFrame);
    outputFramebuffer = [[GPUImageContext sharedFramebufferCache] fetchFramebufferForSize:CGSizeMake(bytesPerRow / 4, bufferHeight) onlyTexture:YES];
    [outputFramebuffer activateFramebuffer];

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, [outputFramebuffer texture]);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, bytesPerRow / 4, bufferHeight, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(cameraFrame));

    [self updateTargetsForVideoCameraUsingCacheTextureAtWidth:bytesPerRow / 4 height:bufferHeight time:currentTime];

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(cameraFrame, 0);

    if (_runBenchmark)
    {
        numberOfFramesCaptured++;
        if (numberOfFramesCaptured > INITIALFRAMESTOIGNOREFORBENCHMARK)
        {
            CFAbsoluteTime currentFrameTime = (CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime);
            totalFrameTimeDuringCapture += currentFrameTime;
        }
    }
}  
}
```

For reference the example code in the OpenGL example is the SimpleVideoFilter - Any help on how to go about adding proper Pausing functionality from someone experience of this OpenGL code would be great thank you - Chaz

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error worked out a way that seems pretty robust merging the two code samples above so for anyone using the OpenGl framework from Brad Larson you can put this Property in to the GPUImageVideoCamera.h:

```
@property(readwrite, nonatomic) BOOL discont;
```

and this code in to the in place of the captureoutput function in the GPUImageVideoCamera.m file

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
if (!self.captureSession.isRunning)
{
    return;
}
if (capturePaused)
{
    return;
}
else if (captureOutput == audioOutput)
{
    [self processAudioSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
}
else
{
    if (dispatch_semaphore_wait(frameRenderingSemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW) != 0)
    {
        return;
    }

if (_discont)
{
    _discont = NO;
    // calc adjustment
    CMTime pts = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);
    CMTime last = _lastVideo;
    if (last.flags & kCMTimeFlags_Valid)
    {
        if (_timeOffset.flags & kCMTimeFlags_Valid)
        {
            pts = CMTimeSubtract(pts, _timeOffset);
        }
        CMTime offset = CMTimeSubtract(pts, last);
        NSLog(@"Adding %f to %f (pts %f)", ((double)offset.value)/offset.timescale, ((double)_timeOffset.value)/_timeOffset.timescale, ((double)pts.value/pts.timescale));

        // this stops us having to set a scale for _timeOffset before we see the first video time
        if (_timeOffset.value == 0)
        {
            _timeOffset = offset;
        }
        else
        {
            _timeOffset = CMTimeAdd(_timeOffset, offset);
        }

    }
    _lastVideo.flags = 0;
    _lastAudio.flags = 0;
}
// retain so that we can release either this or modified one
CFRetain(sampleBuffer);

if (_timeOffset.value > 0)
{
    CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
    sampleBuffer = [self adjustTime:sampleBuffer by:_timeOffset];
}

// record most recent time so we know the length of the pause
CMTime pts = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);
CMTime dur = CMSampleBufferGetDuration(sampleBuffer);
if (dur.value > 0)
{
    pts = CMTimeAdd(pts, dur);
}
_lastVideo = pts;

    runAsynchronouslyOnVideoProcessingQueue(^{
        //Feature Detection Hook.
        if (self.delegate)
        {
            [self.delegate willOutputSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
        }

        [self processVideoSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];

        CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(frameRenderingSemaphore);
    });
}
}
```

From your main Viewcontroller the code is super simple (listed as button actions but can be put most places) and make sure you list _discont = NO on startup to keep it clean:

```
- (IBAction)PauseButton:(id)sender 
{
[videoCamera pauseCameraCapture];
videoCamera.discont = YES;
}

- (IBAction)ResumeButton:(id)sender 
{
    [videoCamera resumeCameraCapture];
}
```

Hope this helps anyone facing the same challenge